# Matching Street names with GPS data?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, gps

I have a list with over 10000 street names and places. These street names indicate where Radar Speed controls are located in Germany. I Need to have a map, where those Points are tagged. I did this for about 200 streets manually but it takes a lot of time.

Does anyone know a solution how to get this done automatically?

Does this work with QGIS and OpenStreetMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at this plugin in https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeoCoding/ I'm very new to qgis so haven't tried it yet

Comment: The GeoCoding plugin only does one address at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Michael! In the end I used the MMQGIS plugin. This Website http://blog.mangomap.com/post/74368997570/how-to-make-a-web-map-from-a-list-of-addresses-in describes how to use it.

Comment: MMQGIS ended up saving me alot of time geocoding as well, thanks @HausladenCarina for pointing it out by updating your question

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the python package geopy http://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ 
While you didn't mention whether you wanted a code free solution its not too difficult to get a functioning script up and running that would take your list and using your preferred supported geocoder get the long and lat values